# Как разрешить структуре инициализацию как через конструктор так и через {}

Tags: c++

ситуация следующая
Есть два класса A и B, я хочу чтоб структуру A можно было инициализировать через {}
тоесть A{1, 2, 3} и через конструктор из структуры B, тоесть A(B). Проблема в том что когда я создаю конструктор, не могу инициализировать через скобки.

Comment: для `A{1, 2, 3}` надо реализовать конструктор с 3 аргументами (т.к. для типа с хотя бы одним конструктором уже не будет работать агрегатная инициализация). вместо `A(B)` следует писать `A{B}`

Comment: Непонятно, в чем ваша проблема... https://ideone.com/mG8ma0 — что здесь не так?